# Add property value from object to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array object and an object with the same amount of properties that array has.

I need to attach property values from object to every object of an array.
To fill a value property

**Array**

```
0: {number: "1", type: "date", placeholder: "Semana", validations: Array(1), value: "value"}
1: {number: "2", type: "text", placeholder: "Marca", validations: Array(3), value: "value"}
[n]
```

**Object**

```
0: "23"
1: "34"
2: "sdfds"
[n]
```

**Code**

```
this.dataForm.forEach( (el) => {
    Object.entries(formObject).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      el.value = value
    })
})
```

Can you help with it?

**Expected result**

```
0: {number: "1", type: "date", placeholder: "Semana", validations: Array(1), value: 23}
1: {number: "2", type: "text", placeholder: "Marca", validations: Array(3), value: 34}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map()`

```js
const arr = [{number: "1", type: "date", placeholder: "Semana", validations: Array(1), value: "value"},
{number: "2", type: "text", placeholder: "Marca", validations: Array(3), value: "value"}]

const obj = {
  0: "23",
  1: "34",
  2: "sdfds"
}

const res = arr.map((x,i) => ({...x,value:obj[i]}))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: @MikeKylmäLampi Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied with answer.

Comment: have to wait 10 minutes at least

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach and access the actual index in each iteration to assing the proper value:

```
data = [
    {number: "1", type: "date", placeholder: "Semana", validations: Array(1), value: "value"},
    {number: "2", type: "text", placeholder: "Marca", validations: Array(3), value: "value"}
  ]
values = ["23", "34"]

// Here you do the magic :)
data.forEach((row, index) => row.value = values[index])
```